# HTACCESS to NGINX Conversoin

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx, plesk

I'm trying to convert the following HTACCESS file into NGINX. I'm on a Plesk server using the built-in converter through the Plesk GUI and it does not seem to be working (keeps generating an error due to the SetEnvIf variable).

The converters I've tried all keep the SetEnvIf variable which does not work in NGINX. NGINX uses an "env" equivalent I believe, however, when I input that into the Plesk GUI for NGINX Settings (which in turn writes to the nginx.conf file in our main server configuration), I get another error message that states we cannot use the "env" variable in this location.

Here is the HTACCESS file we need to convert:

```
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
  SetEnvIf Authorization .+ HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$0
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options -MultiViews
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /discuss/api/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule .* index.php [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
</IfModule>
```

This is what the converter, and others, create:

```
if (!-f $request_filename){
  set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
}
if (!-d $request_filename){
  set $rule_0 2$rule_0;
}
if ($rule_0 = "21"){
  setenv HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:$http_authorization;
  rewrite /.* /index.php last;
}
```

What are we doing wrong (and the converters)?! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The [context](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#env) of `env` is `main` so it can't be used in virtual server:

```
env FOO=BAR; // main context
http {
   server {
       // we a here
   }
}
```

But you can access HTTP_AUTHORIZATION and set environment variable from PHP code in `index.php`:

```
<?php
    putenv('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=' . $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']);
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but that will not work in our case. We need to convert the above HTACCESS into the NGINX equivalent for input into the NGINX configuration files via the Plesk NGINX GUI. It's in support of IP Board API calls.